# What is special about numbers starting with zero?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, compiler-construction, numbers

This is kinda stupid question, but it's interesting for me )

This is what i get with visual studio 2013

```
int i = 07;     // i == 7
int i = 16;     // i == 16
int i = 00016;  // i == 14, why?
int i = 05016;  // i == 2574, wow )
int i = 08;     // compile error, compiler expects octal number...
```

If number starts with zero and contains 8, it's compile error. Is this normal? And what exactly compiler does with starting zeros if 00016 == 14?

Thanks to all ))

Comment: Octal integer literals. (As should be covered by any basic C or C++ tutorial.)

Comment: Well done for correctly and thoroughly identifying a pattern. :) Not so well done for not performing any subsequent research! :(

Comment: the compiler message containing the word "octal" kind of gave it away...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is expected.

> `[C++11: 2.14.2/1]:` An *integer literal* is a sequence of digits that has no period or exponent part. An integer literal may have a prefix that specifies its base and a suffix that specifies its type. The lexically first digit of the sequence of digits is the most significant. A *decimal* integer literal (base ten) begins with a digit other than 0 and consists of a sequence of decimal digits. **An *octal* integer literal (base eight) begins with the digit 0 and consists of a sequence of octal digits.**<sup>22</sup> A *hexadecimal* integer literal (base sixteen) begins with 0x or 0X and consists of a sequence of hexadecimal digits, which include the decimal digits and the letters a through f and A through F with decimal values ten through fifteen. *[ Example:* the number twelve can be written 12, 014, or 0XC. *—end example ]*
>
> <sup><sup>22</sup> **The digits 8 and 9 are not octal digits.**</sup>

Answer (score 6):

An integer literal that starts with `0` is an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), much like a number starting with `0x`is a hexadecimal number.

Octal numbers can only contain the digits `0` to `7`, and this is why you get a compilation error.

Answer (score 5):

Integer literals that start with `0` are *octal* literals. Therefore they must only contain the digits 0–7.

(Amusingly, this includes the literal `0` itself.)

Comment: What's so amusing about it? :/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I've repeatedly used that factoid as an ice breaker in my monthly standup routines. You need to build it up a bit, I suppose.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't think people would expect 0 to be an octal literal.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Why not? What other arbitrary choice of base would you prefer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit nothing. If people could *once* read thru a beginner turorial attentively, that would be amusing.

Comment: @KerrekSB: C++ Stand-up? Sign me up!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe base 10? That's what I thought at first.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Why? Of what importance is the base when you are discussing zero?

Comment: @0x499602D2: PHP considers `0` to be [a decimal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No importance. It's just that I don't think base 8 is the first thing one would think of when asked the base of 0.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It is, in fact, the simplest possible choice in this case: To define it as some other base would require an exception for the case when the integer literal is only one character long and begins with zero.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Well given that you cannot explain _why_, I do not accept your proposition!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes and that PHP grammar is more complicated for it. Not prohibitively so, and frankly even barely notably so, but more than not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Note that I am being completely subjective! That's why I agreed that it can be amusing.

Answer (score 3):

Starting a number with 0 makes it Octal, so digits 8 and 9 are illegal, and your other examples show conversion to decimal.