# Age output not calculating

Tags: c++

```
PatientDemographicInformation patientJones("123456789", "Jones", 
                                              'A', "Mary", 
                                              "Mc Donalds Department, 555 Elm Street, Apt 2, 
                                              "666 West Side", 
                                              "San Diego", "ca", "76032", "3899", 
                                              "360", "89054392012", 
                                              'f', 02031934);

patientJones.printPatientDemographicInformation();

int PatientDemographicInformation::getPatientAge( )
{  
       time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
       struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
       int yearNow = (now->tm_year + 1900);
       int birthYear  =  (patientDateOfBirth % 10000); 
       return yearNow - birthYear; 

}
```

main.cpp:27:50: error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant <-- This is the error...

It will not calculate certain years with certain months and days. 
I used 11171993 as the birth date and it worked. Although, I need the birth date of 02031934 and genuinely any date to work. Any help is welcome.

Thank You!

Comment: only post code enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry, first time asking a question. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf.aspx), the beginning of an integer constant with `0`, as in `01011967`, indicates octal notation, which consequently makes it impossible to use `9` in the constant.

Comment: Thank you! Although this only solves my issue for the time being, I need to use this same calculation later down the road to take input from a user. Is there anyway to configure this to take any input with a leading 0?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your number literal starts with a 0. See here:
[What is special about numbers starting with zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568200/what-is-special-about-numbers-starting-with-zero)

If you want to have the same number, either take out the 0, leaving `1011967`, or change it to a string like you've done with the rest of your numbers.

Comment: Yeah it does work with taking out the leading 0, but i'm going to later down the road use this same function for input program. Is there anyway I can make it possible to take the 01011967?

Comment: @LuckyDreamer just write `1011967` instead of `01011967`. Where is the problem ? If you start a number with 0, then it's an octal number. That's it. Period.

Comment: @Michael Walz Yes, but this is only a temporary fix for the constructor. I will need to use this same function to take input from a user and calculate anything with a leading 0 for their birth date.

Comment: @LuckyDreamer user input is a different story than literals in the program.  You won't have that sort of problems with user input.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Okay, thank you!