# Bitwise OR Operator

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code:

```
int ret() {
    int x = 010;
    int y = 4;
    int z = x | y;
    return z;
}
```

When x = 010, this function returns 12. However, on changing x to 10, 14 is returned. Why is this so?

Comment: Binary integer literals was introduced with C++14 and uses the prefix `0b`. As in `0b10` for the integer value 2.

Comment: It's a pity `0o` wasn't adopted for octal literals in C++14 with an eye to deprecating the leading `0` without the `o` in a future standard.

Comment: It's a pity octal literals aren't deprecated outright. I could perhaps live with `10_octal`.

Comment: Another possible dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26568200/1896169 . There are a lot of these questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OR operator is a red-herring: the issue is elsewhere.

`010` is an *octal* literal due to the leading `0`. In decimal, this is `8`.

So `x` has the value `8` in decimal. And `8 | 4` is `12`.

`10` is a decimal literal. And `10 | 4` is `14`.