# Invalid integer in C

Tags: c

Why does C not accept `08` and `09` as an integer? Are there ways that I could still validate the `08` and `09` as an integer?

```c
int main(){
    int a;
    scanf("%i", &a);

    if (a== 8 || a==08){
        printf("Octagon");
    }
    else if (a== 9 || a==09){
        printf("Nonagon");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `08`, and how would it be different from `8`?

Comment: by the way you missed `&` , should be `scanf("%i", &a);`

Comment: What exactly are you expecting it to do? `08`, if octal weren't a thing, would be equivalent to `8`, so I'm not sure why you were testing for both; you parsed it from a string, so it's no longer a string, and has no concept of leading zeroes anymore.

Comment: C++ but close enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568200/what-is-special-about-numbers-starting-with-zero

Comment: I'm considering the possibility that the user inputs 08, not 8.

Comment: @CodeBeginner: If the user input `08`, since you used `%i` as the `scanf` format code, it wouldn't work correctly anyway; `%i` looks for and handles prefixes like `0` (meaning octal) and `0x`/`0X` (hex) so it would try to parse it as octal and fail (and you'd never know, because you're not checking the return value from `scanf`; it'll have whatever was in `a` originally). If you want to handle strict decimal inputs, use `%d`, and the leading zeroes will be ignored (you'll get `8` no matter how many zeroes they prefix it with, because there is no such thing as an `int` with a *value* of `08`).

Comment: You're comparing the numeric value, not the string representation.

Comment: Unrelated note: Always, *always* check the return value from `scanf`. It might be zero or EOF. You can only use the value of `a` in your program if `scanf` returned exactly `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you look carefully at the compiler error, it will mention that you have specified an invalid *octal* constant.

This is because any number that begins with a `0` (that isn't followed by an `x`) is interpreted as an octal constant. Valid digits for octal constants are `0`-`7`, with `8` and `9` being invalid.

The simple solution is to remove the leading zeroes.

Note that you're comparing an `int` with the values of eight and nine. Even if the user input a number with a leading zero, the binary representation of the integer value does not store that fact. Looking for a leading zero *might* be useful if you were looking at a string rather than an integer.